# CKEditor: прикрепить файл

Tags: редактор-текста, ckeditor, редактор

Добрый день! Нужно сделать возможность прикрепления файлов. Возможно кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим? В самом CKE не найду этой функции. У меня используется связка CKEditor + CKFinder..

Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: вряд ли можно с CKeditor - ом. Думаю нужно отдельное ***<input type="file">***

Answer (score 4):

Не понял, в чем проблема? Подключаем `ckeditor` и `ckfinder` и загружаем файлы на сервер. Сам недавно подключал. Все без проблем. Сейчас только надо настроить конкретную дерикторию для загрузки файлов.

Если надо можем обсудить, подскажу - что смогу.

Answer (score 3):

Нет! Я решил эту проблему. Нашел информацию на каком-то из сайтов. Сейчас расскажу:
Подключаем JS файл на необходимую нам страницу

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
```

Далее две JS функции:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function browseServer()
    {
        var finder = new CKFinder();
        finder.basePath = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/ckfinder/';
        finder.selectActionFunction = SetFileField;
        finder.popup(); 
    }

    function SetFileField(fileUrl, data)
    {
        $('#attachment').append(fileName + ' (' + data["fileSize"] + ' Kb)');
    }   
</script>
```

И кнопочка:

```
<input type="button" value="Прикрепить файл" onclick="browseServer('Files:/', 'attachment');">
```

Добавление файлов происходит в элемент с ID 'attachment'.

В примере для добавления используется jQuery

Comment: Привет. Маленький вопросик. Если сделать так, как приведено в примере, то получается кнопка которая выводит в ckfinder и дает возможность загрузить файл и т.п. Вопрос. Отсюда вопрос, как сделать так, что бы (например при клике по изображению "выбрать" в ckfinder в какое-то поле передавалась ссылка на файл. Потому-что, как я вижу, ваша система дает возможность только загрузить файл на сервер.

Comment: Это то, что Вам нужно.. Если все же я не правильно Вам понял, то сформируйте вопрос иначе..